# Find rows with adjourning date ranges and accumulate their durations

Tags: sql, postgresql

My PostgreSQL database stores school vacation, public holidays and weekend dates for parents to plan their vacation. Many times school vacations are adjourned by weekends or public holidays. I want to display the total number of non-school days for a school vacation. That should include any adjourned weekend or public holiday.

## Example Data

**locations**

```sql
SELECT id, name, is_federal_state 
FROM locations 
WHERE is_federal_state = true;
```

```
| id | name              | is_federal_state |
|----|-------------------|------------------|
| 2  | Baden-Württemberg | true             |
| 3  | Bayern            | true             |
```

**holiday_or_vacation_types**

```
SELECT id, name FROM holiday_or_vacation_types;
```

```
| id | name                  |
|----|-----------------------|
| 1  | Herbst                |
| 8  | Wochenende            |
```

"Herbst" is German for "autumn" and "Wochenende" is German for "weekend".

**periods**

```
SELECT id, starts_on, ends_on, holiday_or_vacation_type_id 
FROM periods 
WHERE location_id = 2 
ORDER BY starts_on;
```

```
| id  | starts_on    | ends_on      | holiday_or_vacation_type_id |
|-----|--------------|--------------|-----------------------------|
| 670 | "2019-10-26" | "2019-10-27" | 8                           |
| 532 | "2019-10-28" | "2019-10-30" | 1                           |
| 533 | "2019-10-31" | "2019-10-31" | 1                           |
| 671 | "2019-11-02" | "2019-11-03" | 8                           |
| 672 | "2019-11-09" | "2019-11-10" | 8                           |
| 673 | "2019-11-16" | "2019-11-17" | 8                           |
```

## Task

I want to `select` all `periods` where `location_id` equals 2. And I want to calculate the duration of each period in days. That can be done with this SQL query:

```
SELECT id, starts_on, ends_on, 
       (ends_on - starts_on + 1) AS duration, 
       holiday_or_vacation_type_id 
FROM periods
```

```
| id  | starts_on    | ends_on      | duration | holiday_or_vacation_type_id |
|-----|--------------|--------------|----------|-----------------------------|
| 670 | "2019-10-26" | "2019-10-27" | 2        | 8                           |
| 532 | "2019-10-28" | "2019-10-30" | 3        | 1                           |
| 533 | "2019-10-31" | "2019-10-31" | 1        | 1                           |
| 671 | "2019-11-02" | "2019-11-03" | 2        | 8                           |
| 672 | "2019-11-09" | "2019-11-10" | 2        | 8                           |
| 673 | "2019-11-16" | "2019-11-17" | 2        | 8                           |
```

*Any human looking at the calendar would see that the ids 670 (weekend), 532 (fall vacation) and 533 (fall vacation) are adjourned. So they add up to a 6 day vacation period.* So far I do this with a program which computes this. But that takes quite a lot of resources (the actual table contains some 500,000 items).

### Problem 1

Which SQL query would result in the following output (is adds a `real_duration` column)? Is that even possible with SQL?

```
| id  | starts_on    | ends_on      | duration | real_duration | holiday_or_vacation_type_id |
|-----|--------------|--------------|----------|---------------|-----------------------------|
| 670 | "2019-10-26" | "2019-10-27" | 2        | 6             | 8                           |
| 532 | "2019-10-28" | "2019-10-30" | 3        | 6             | 1                           |
| 533 | "2019-10-31" | "2019-10-31" | 1        | 6             | 1                           |
| 671 | "2019-11-02" | "2019-11-03" | 2        | 2             | 8                           |
| 672 | "2019-11-09" | "2019-11-10" | 2        | 2             | 8                           |
| 673 | "2019-11-16" | "2019-11-17" | 2        | 2             | 8                           |
```

### Problem 2

It is possible to list the adjourning periods in a `part_of_range` field? This would be the result. Can that be done with SQL?

```
| id  | starts_on    | ends_on      | duration | part_of_range | holiday_or_vacation_type_id |
|-----|--------------|--------------|----------|---------------|-----------------------------|
| 670 | "2019-10-26" | "2019-10-27" | 2        | 670,532,533   | 8                           |
| 532 | "2019-10-28" | "2019-10-30" | 3        | 670,532,533   | 1                           |
| 533 | "2019-10-31" | "2019-10-31" | 1        | 670,532,533   | 1                           |
| 671 | "2019-11-02" | "2019-11-03" | 2        |               | 8                           |
| 672 | "2019-11-09" | "2019-11-10" | 2        |               | 8                           |
| 673 | "2019-11-16" | "2019-11-17" | 2        |               | 8                           |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gaps and islands problem.  In this case you can use `lag()` to see where an island starts and then a cumulative sum.

The final operation is some aggregation (using window functions):

```
SELECT p.*, 
      (Max(ends_on) OVER (PARTITION BY location_id, grp) - Min(starts_on) OVER (PARTITION BY location_id, grp) ) + 1 AS duration,
      Array_agg(p.id) OVER (PARTITION BY location_id) 
FROM (SELECT p.*, 
             Count(*) FILTER (WHERE prev_eo < starts_on - INTERVAL '1 day') OVER (PARTITION BY location_id ORDER BY starts_on) AS grp
      FROM (SELECT id, starts_on, ends_on, location_id, holiday_or_vacation_type_id, 
                   lag(ends_on) OVER (PARTITION BY location_id ORDER BY (starts_on)) AS prev_eo
            FROM periods 
           ) p
     ) p;
```