# Gaps and islands for school vacations in a country with federal states

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

The `periods` table contains data of periods where school is off for students. The `locations` table contains countries and federal states. I want to list all periods from the '2019-12-15' to the '2020-01-15' and accumulate the total number of off days for each island.

To collect the data I have to search for all periods of the location 1 and the location 2. Because e.g. weekends are periods which are associated to the country and school vacations are associated to the federal state.

### The Data

All data is stored in a PostgreSQL database. I have no control over the table structure.

**locations**

```
|----|-------------------|------------------|------------|
| id |       name        | is_federal_state | is_country |
|----|-------------------|------------------|------------|
|  1 | Deutschland       | f                | t          |
|  2 | Baden-Württemberg | t                | f          |
|----|-------------------|------------------|------------|
```

"Deutschland" is the country Germany. "Baden-Württemberg" is a federal state of Germany.

**periods**

```
|-----|------------|------------|-------------|
| id  | starts_on  |  ends_on   | location_id |
|-----|------------|------------|-------------|
| 678 | 2019-12-21 | 2019-12-22 |           1 |
| 534 | 2019-12-23 | 2020-01-04 |           2 |
| 679 | 2019-12-28 | 2019-12-29 |           1 |
|   9 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-01 |           2 |
| 776 | 2020-01-04 | 2020-01-05 |           1 |
|   7 | 2020-01-06 | 2020-01-06 |           2 |
| 777 | 2020-01-11 | 2020-01-12 |           1 |
|-----|------------|------------|-------------|
```

The `periods` table stores information about periods where students don't have to attend school. 678, 679, 776 and 777 are weekends which are associated to the country (id 1). The other are school vacations or public holidays which are associated to the federal state (id 2).

### The Query

With the help of [Find rows with adjourning date ranges and accumulate their durations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60111734/find-rows-with-adjourning-date-ranges-and-accumulate-their-durations/60113333) I found out that this is a gaps and islands problem. But I don't understand how I can use this properly. This is what I have:

```
SELECT
  p.*,
  (
      Max(ends_on) OVER (PARTITION BY location_id) - Min(starts_on) OVER (PARTITION BY location_id) 
  )
  + 1 AS duration  
FROM
  (
      SELECT
        p.*,
        Count(*) FILTER (
      WHERE
        prev_eo < starts_on - INTERVAL '1 day') OVER (PARTITION BY location_id 
      ORDER BY
        starts_on) AS grp 
      FROM
        (
            SELECT
              id,
              starts_on,
              ends_on,
              location_id,
              lag(ends_on) OVER (PARTITION BY location_id 
            ORDER BY
(starts_on)) AS prev_eo 
            FROM
              periods 
            WHERE
              location_id IN 
              (
                  1,
                  2
              )
              AND starts_on > '2019-12-15' 
              AND starts_on < '2020-01-15' 
        )
        p 
  )
  p;
```

### The Result

```
|-----|------------|------------|-------------|-----|----------|
| id  | starts_on  |  ends_on   | location_id | grp | duration |
|-----|------------|------------|-------------|-----|----------|
| 678 | 2019-12-21 | 2019-12-22 |           1 |   0 |       23 |
| 679 | 2019-12-28 | 2019-12-29 |           1 |   1 |       23 |
| 776 | 2020-01-04 | 2020-01-05 |           1 |   2 |       23 |
| 777 | 2020-01-11 | 2020-01-12 |           1 |   3 |       23 |
| 534 | 2019-12-23 | 2020-01-04 |           2 |   0 |       15 |
|   9 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-01 |           2 |   0 |       15 |
|   7 | 2020-01-06 | 2020-01-06 |           2 |   1 |       15 |
|-----|------------|------------|-------------|-----|----------|
```

Problems with this result:

- This result assumes that all weekends of location ID 1 are one big island. But they aren't. All but one weekend belong to the Christmas vacation island.
- The actual Christmas vacation of ID 2 should result in a duration of 15 which would include period id 678 which should be part of the Christmas island (plus the other weekends in that period).

### The result I want

```
|-----|------------|------------|-------------|----------|
| id  | starts_on  |  ends_on   | location_id | duration |
|-----|------------|------------|-------------|----------|
| 678 | 2019-12-21 | 2019-12-22 |           1 |       15 |
| 679 | 2019-12-28 | 2019-12-29 |           1 |       15 |
| 776 | 2020-01-04 | 2020-01-05 |           1 |       15 |
| 777 | 2020-01-11 | 2020-01-12 |           1 |        2 |
| 534 | 2019-12-23 | 2020-01-04 |           2 |       15 |
|   9 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-01 |           2 |       15 |
|   7 | 2020-01-06 | 2020-01-06 |           2 |       15 |
|-----|------------|------------|-------------|----------|
```

*Which query will generate in this result?*

### Playground

All the data and the query: https://rextester.com/FEL57082

Comment: I don't understand how the "17"s are calculated.

Comment: Another problem that is likely to cause trouble is how dates are being used.  Normally, the 23rd to the 24th is 1 day; you're using it to mean two.  Similarly, the 21st to 22nd, plus also the 23rd to 24th, would normally not include the 22nd to 23rd.  In effect, if each date is implicitly placed at midnight, every end date will need one day added to it, in order for most date math to work as expected.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I fixed the number. It should have been 15. 13 days for period with the id 534 plus 2 from the period 678.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in the code.  The `grp` is calculated, but not used.  So, I think you want:

```
SELECT p.*,
       (Max(ends_on) OVER (PARTITION BY location_id, grp) - Min(starts_on) OVER (PARTITION BY location_id, grp) 
       ) + 1 AS duration 
FROM (SELECT p.*,
             Count(*) FILTER (WHERE prev_eo < starts_on - INTERVAL '1 day') OVER
                 (PARTITION BY location_id 
                  ORDER BY starts_on
                 ) AS grp 
      FROM (SELECT p.*,
                   lag(ends_on) OVER (PARTITION BY location_id ORDER BY starts_on) AS prev_eo 
            FROM periods p
            WHERE location_id IN (1, 2) AND
                  starts_on > '2019-12-15' AND
                  starts_on < '2020-01-15' 
          ) p 
  ) p;
```

However, this returns `2` for the weekends, not `17`.

[Here](https://rextester.com/VLHKG23258) is your Rextester with this query.

Comment: But the result of the period 534 should be 15 and not 13. The period 678 adjourns to it.