# Overlapping gaps and islands in a school vacation setup

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

I have to work with this `periods` table:

**periods**

```
id  | starts_on  |  ends_on   
----+------------+------------
678 | 2019-12-21 | 2019-12-22
534 | 2019-12-23 | 2020-01-04
679 | 2019-12-28 | 2019-12-29
  9 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-01
776 | 2020-01-04 | 2020-01-05
  7 | 2020-01-06 | 2020-01-06
777 | 2020-01-11 | 2020-01-12
```

It lists all periods where students don't have to go to school. Unfortunately some of the periods overlap. This happens when during a school vacation a weekend or a public holiday occurs (each of them have their own periods rows).

With the help of [Find rows with adjourning date ranges and accumulate their durations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60111734/find-rows-with-adjourning-date-ranges-and-accumulate-their-durations/60113333) and [Gaps and islands for school vacations in a country with federal states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60120669/gaps-and-islands-for-school-vacations-in-a-country-with-federal-states?noredirect=1#comment106333440_60120669) I ended up with this query:

```sql
SELECT p.id, p.starts_on, p.ends_on, grp,
      (Max(ends_on) OVER (PARTITION BY grp) - Min(starts_on) OVER (PARTITION BY grp) 
      ) + 1 AS duration, Array_agg(p.id) OVER (PARTITION BY grp) 
FROM (SELECT p.*,
            Count(*) FILTER (WHERE prev_eo < starts_on - INTERVAL '1 day') OVER
                (PARTITION BY 1 
                  ORDER BY starts_on
                ) AS grp 
      FROM (SELECT p.*,
                  lag(ends_on) OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY starts_on) AS prev_eo 
            FROM (SELECT p.id, p.starts_on, p.ends_on FROM periods p
            WHERE starts_on > '2019-12-15' AND
                  starts_on < '2020-01-15' ) p 
          ) p 
  ) p;
```

### What I get

It results in

```
id  | starts_on  |  ends_on   | grp | duration |   array_agg   
----+------------+------------+-----+----------+---------------
678 | 2019-12-21 | 2019-12-22 |   0 |       15 | {678,534,679}
534 | 2019-12-23 | 2020-01-04 |   0 |       15 | {678,534,679}
679 | 2019-12-28 | 2019-12-29 |   0 |       15 | {678,534,679}
  9 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-01 |   1 |        1 | {9}
776 | 2020-01-04 | 2020-01-05 |   2 |        3 | {776,7}
  7 | 2020-01-06 | 2020-01-06 |   2 |        3 | {776,7}
777 | 2020-01-11 | 2020-01-12 |   3 |        2 | {777}
```

The first three lines are the `grp` 0 (ids 678, 534 and 679).

### What I want

But the ids 9, 776 and 7 should belong to that `grp` too. Unfortunately they overlap. Is it possible to get a result which is somehow like this (I don't care about the order)?

```
id  | starts_on  |  ends_on   | grp | duration |   array_agg   
----+------------+------------+-----+----------+---------------
678 | 2019-12-21 | 2019-12-22 |   0 |       17 | {678,534,679,9,776,7}
534 | 2019-12-23 | 2020-01-04 |   0 |       17 | {678,534,679,9,776,7}
679 | 2019-12-28 | 2019-12-29 |   0 |       17 | {678,534,679,9,776,7}
  9 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-01 |   0 |       17 | {678,534,679,9,776,7}
776 | 2020-01-04 | 2020-01-05 |   0 |       17 | {678,534,679,9,776,7}
  7 | 2020-01-06 | 2020-01-06 |   0 |       17 | {678,534,679,9,776,7}
777 | 2020-01-11 | 2020-01-12 |   1 |        2 | {777}
```

I want to know how long the total island (grp 0) is in days and which period ids it contains.

Sandbox: https://rextester.com/SHVL41709

Comment: Hi WIntermeyer. if you dont mind, how grp and duration are computed here?

Comment: grp: `Count(*) FILTER (WHERE prev_eo < starts_on - INTERVAL '1 day') OVER
                (PARTITION BY 1 
                  ORDER BY starts_on
                ) AS grp`

Comment: duration: `(Max(ends_on) OVER (PARTITION BY grp) - Min(starts_on) OVER (PARTITION BY grp) 
      ) + 1 AS duration`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting variant of your other problems.  The issue is that `lag()` only looks at the one preceding row to check for an overlap.  Instead, you want to look at all preceding rows.

Fortunately, you can use a cumulative `max()` for this purpose:

```
SELECT p.id, p.starts_on, p.ends_on, grp,
      (Max(ends_on) OVER (PARTITION BY grp) - Min(starts_on) OVER (PARTITION BY grp) 
      ) + 1 AS duration, Array_agg(p.id) OVER (PARTITION BY grp) 
FROM (SELECT p.*,
            Count(*) FILTER (WHERE prev_eo < starts_on - INTERVAL '1 day') OVER
                (PARTITION BY 1 
                  ORDER BY starts_on
                ) AS grp 
      FROM (SELECT p.*,
                  MAX(ends_on) OVER (ORDER BY starts_on ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS prev_eo 
            FROM (SELECT p.id, p.starts_on, p.ends_on 
                  FROM periods p
                  WHERE starts_on > '2019-12-15' AND
                        starts_on < '2020-01-15'
                 ) p 
          ) p 
  ) p;
```

I'm not sure what the `PARTITION BY 1` is supposed to be doing, but I didn't include it.

[Here](https://rextester.com/SHVL41709) is a rextester.

To anticipate your next question.  This has one challenge:  if the start times are ever equal, then the cumulative max is not stable.  In that case, you either want to remove the duplicates or make the sorting for the cumulative max stable.